# Обязательно ли одна команда должна находиться на одной строке?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли сделать валидным в JavaScript подобное:

```js
var string = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so :insertx: went for a walk.
    When they got to :inserty:, they stared in horror for a few moments, then :insertz:. 
    Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — :insertx: weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), которые допускают внутри себя переносы строк:

```js
var string = `It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so :insertx: went for a walk.
    When they got to :inserty:, they stared in horror for a few moments, then :insertz:. 
    Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — :insertx: weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.`;
```

Также можно добавить экранирование переносов:

```js
var string = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so :insertx: went for a walk. \
    When they got to :inserty:, they stared in horror for a few moments, then :insertz:. \
    Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — :insertx: weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.';
```